Flutter AppBar that always stays no matter what
AIM: I wish to make my flutter app also on the web, hence, like most websites, I want it to have an AppBar that is always there no matter how many screens (routes) I push or where I navigate.
PROBLEM: However, when I do Navigator.push(), the AppBar disappears, since a new Scaffold is created with it's own AppBar.
QUESTION: Is there any way to achieve a constant AppBar in my flutter app?
WHAT I TRIED: I tried using IndexedStack, which worked for my main screens. However, when I want to navigate from one of my main screens (which are in the indexed stack), this approach fails.

you should have only one scaffold with that app bar, and navigate between bodies not scaffolds (scaffold remains persistent (with it's app bar) and the body changes)

You should try with go_router which has a shell route and gives you opportunities to keep the app bar always there like a web app please check the given example.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      routerConfig: _router,
    );
  }
}

final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
  initialLocation: '/home',
  routes: [
    ShellRoute(
      builder: (context, state, child) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Shell Route Example')),
          drawer: Drawer(
            child: ListView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              children: <Widget>[
                 const DrawerHeader(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  child: Text('Navigation Drawer'),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: Text('Home'),
                  onTap: () {
                    context.pop();
                    context.go('/home');

                  },
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: Text('Settings'),
                  onTap: () {
                    context.pop();
                    context.go('/settings');
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          body: child,
        );
      },
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: '/home',
          builder: (context, state) => HomeScreen(),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: '/settings',
          builder: (context, state) => SettingsScreen(),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(child: Text('Home Screen'));
  }
}

class SettingsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(child: Text('Settings Screen'));
  }
}


return MaterialApp(
  builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) => Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
  ),
  home: MyHomePage(),
);

Edit
sorry, the above doesn't work so here is the solution:
use MyPage as a template to any of your pages.
the Hero widget is to keep the app bar at place in route transitions
class MyPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyPage({super.key, required this.body});
  
  final Widget body;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: [
          body,
          Positioned(
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            child: MyAppBar(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyAppBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyAppBar({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Hero(
      tag: 'appBar',
      child: child,// todo
    );
  }
}


You can use bottomNavigationBar parameter of the Scaffold() widget,
or you can use another creative alternative like this (using go_router package):
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

void main() {
// To show deep linking in browser
GoRouter.optionURLReflectsImperativeAPIs = true;
runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
const MyApp({super.key});
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
        title: 'DemoApp',
        routerConfig: appRouter,
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false);
}
}

// --- Routes (go_router package)
final appRouter = GoRouter(
initialLocation: '/',
routes: [
    GoRoute(path: '/', builder: (context, state) => const HomePage()),
    GoRoute(path: '/page1', builder: (context, state) => const Page1()),
    GoRoute(path: '/page2', builder: (context, state) => const Page2()),
],
);

// --- Home example
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
const HomePage({super.key});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    appBar: MyAppBar.build(context),
    body: BodyViewMockup.build('Home'),
    );
}
}

final viewRoutes = <Widget>[_HomeView(), _Page1View(), _Page2View()];

class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
const Page1({super.key});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    appBar: MyAppBar.build(context),
    body: BodyViewMockup.build('Page 1'),
    );
}
}

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
const Page2({super.key});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    appBar: MyAppBar.build(context),
    body: BodyViewMockup.build('Page 2'),
    );
}
}

class _HomeView extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) => BodyViewMockup.build('Home');
}

class _Page1View extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) => BodyViewMockup.build('Page 1');
}

class _Page2View extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) => BodyViewMockup.build('Page 2');
}

class BodyViewMockup {
static Widget build(String title) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 50,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text('$title: item $index'));
}
}

class MyAppBar {
static AppBar build(BuildContext context) {
    final path = GoRouterState.of(context).fullPath ?? "";
    var title = "";
    switch (path) {
    case '/page1':
        title = 'Page 1';
        break;
    case '/page2':
        title = 'Page 2';
        break;
    default:
        title = 'Home';
    }
    return AppBar(title: Text(title), actions: [
    path == "/"
        ? Container()
        : IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
            color: path == "/home/:page" ? Colors.grey : null,
            onPressed: () => path == "/home/:page" ? null : context.go('/')),
    IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.looks_one_outlined),
        color: path == "/page1" ? Colors.grey : null,
        onPressed: () => path == "/page1" ? null : context.push('/page1')),
    IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.looks_two_outlined),
        color: path == "/page2" ? Colors.grey : null,
        onPressed: () => path == "/page2" ? null : context.push('/page2'),
    ),
    ]);
}
}

